# Django: No of Instances of a Foreign Key

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a class which has a foreign key relationship with another class.
I need a methord that returns the no. of instances of the second class corresponding to a particular instance of the first class

```
from django.db import models
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

For Instance, I need a methord that returns the no. of Choices to a given Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (take a look at the official Django docs about many-to-one relationships):

```
def num_of_choices(question):
    return question.choice_set.count()
```